# Penalty score probability

Tags: probability

> A footballer has a $0.8$ chance of scoring a penalty. How many
>   penalties does he need to take to score at least two times with a
>   $0.9$ probability?

I tried the negative binomial method ($r=2$), so that becomes $\binom{m-1}{1}\cdot 0.8^2\cdot 0.2^{m-2}$. Or should I use hypergeometrical?

Comment: What are your thoughts? I don´t think that you get an answer if you don´t show a minimum of effort. See also here: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The answer is $4$. However, if you want a more detailed answer you should put a little effort into your question.

Comment: No, hypergeometric distribution is not right. But why you don´t use the binomial distribution? And you can use the converse probability. $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)\geq 0.9$, where $X\sim Bin(n, 0.8)$ Note that the inequality cannot be solved algebraically. Just try out some values for $n$.